# ConTeXt enumerate in margin

Tags: lists, margins, context-mkii

For short answer quiz, I like to provide an answerblank in right margin with same number as the question:

In pdfLaTeX I do this with a `newcommand`:

```
\newcommand{\ansblank}{\leavevmode\marginpar{\labelenumi\hrulefill\raggedright\par}
```

Then in `enumerate` environment:

```
\item\ansblank blah blah
```

In ConTeXt MKIV I can do (thanks to Marco):

```
\definemargindata [mymarginrule] [width=3.5cm,location=right,]
\define\ansblank
    {\inright{\getnumber[itemgroup:itemize]. \thinrules[n=1]}}
```

My problem is that I want to do this in ConTeXt MKII. Why? Euler font does not work for me in MKIV (TeXLive 2012 via MacTeX) and I am not able to keep up with MKIV changes. I want to use ConTeXt because of METAPOST integration and enhancements.

The line:

```
\define\ansblank{\inright\thinrule}
```

works in MKII but only gives a line in the right margin (obviously). Is there a `\getnumber` for MKII?

Sorry, I was not allowed to upload output image in original post (and still can't.) This should show what is desired:

```
1) Write the prime factors of 1001                                1) ___________
```

(Use of NeoEuler in mkiv might be another thread; I've had some trouble with it already.)

Comment: Can you show how the output is supposed to look like? I have a hard time understanding the visual description. Regarding Euler, in MkIV you should use the NeoEuler font (search github).

Comment: Here's the original message: [Enumerate fillinline](http://archive.contextgarden.net/message/20120221.142949.cf3a3b48.en.html)

Comment: BTW, why do you use `\item\ansblank` rather than the interface that Macro proposed? If you only need the margin text for some itemizations, you can use `\defineitemgroup[answeritemize]`, then set `\setupitemgroup[answeritemize][...]` instead of `\setupitemize[...]`, and then use `\startansweritemize ... \stopansweritemize` etc.

Comment: @Aditya: yes, 'setupitemgroup' is better. The '\item\ansblank' is old habit from LaTeX now being broken. Thank  you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `\getnumber` for MkII, but internally itemization are not implemented using `number`s in MkII, rather they are implemented using `counter`s. So, you have to explicitly convert the current item counter to the current item conversion (so that the solution works for `\startitemize[a]` etc.).

The second difference is that MkII does not have `margindata`. Since you do not need to control the stacking of margin content (the main feature of `margindata`, but simply want the margin content to be flushed on the same line where it is called, any of the simpler `margin<something>` will work. In the example below I use `marginline` which flushes in the same line where it is called.

Unlike `margindata`, `marginline` is not set inside a `frame`; so you need to wrap the content in  a `frame` (to get a `\vbox`; which ensures that `thinrules` works).

With these changes, Marco's [original solution](http://archive.contextgarden.net/message/20120221.142949.cf3a3b48.en.html) gets translated to MkII as follows:

```
\setuplayout[rightmargin=3cm, width=fit, backspace=1cm, cutspace=3.2cm]


\definemarginline [mymarginrule] [location=right, width=\rightmarginwidth, distance=\rightmargindistance]

\defineframed
  [marginframed]
  [struct=yes,
   offset=overlay,
   frame=off,
   location=low,
   width=\rightmarginwidth,
   align=flushleft]

\define\myrules
    {\mymarginrule{\marginframed{\convertnumber\currentitemsymbol\currentitemnumber. \thinrules[n=1] }}}

\setupitemgroup [itemize] [a]
\setupitemgroup [itemize] [right=\myrules]

\starttext
    \startitemize
        \startitem \input knuth \stopitem
        \startitem \input ward \stopitem
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Just a follow-up note: with `\setupitemize[continue]` the enumeration continues in the main list through `\stopitemize...\startitemize` but the enumeration in the margins resets to the beginning.

Comment: @kitz: That is part of the reason that the implementation in MkIV uses `numbers` (which honor continue and conversion tags) rather than `counters`.