# ConTeXt: Proper way to place enumerations in margins

Tags: margins, context

Is there a proper way to place and *center* enumerations in (outer)margin that

```
\defineenumeration[MyEnumeration][...]
\inmargin{
  \startMyEnumeration
    ...
  \stopMyEnumeration
}
```

or

```
\defineenumeration[MyEnumeration][...]
\inouter{
  \startMyEnumeration
    ...
  \stopMyEnumeration
}
```

Even that have some issues like not centering enumerations on doubleside: when rightside is good, leftside is on the page edge.

I tried to use `alternative=margin`, `margin=yes` and to play around with each enumeration properties but nothing seems to work.

I also tried to use `\setupmargindata` like in this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55668/stack-margin-text-in-outer-margin-in-context-mk-iv?rq=1) and all kinds of `margins` commands like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75780/213111) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476246/213111) but I could not find a way to do what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `userdata` environment to store the content for your `enumeration` in a buffer.

To place the `enumeration` together with the stored content in the margin you have to create a new `alternative` for the `userdata` environment. In the new `alternative` you can use the `\margindata` (or `\inouter` etc.) command to put the `enumeration` together with the content in the desired margin.

Below is a example for this method

```
\defineenumeration
  [MyEnumeration]
  [alternative=top,
   before=,
   after=,
   inbetween=,
   title=yes,
   text=Enum.]

\defineuserdataalternative
  [enumeration]
  [renderingsetup=enumeration:margin]

\startsetups[enumeration:margin]
  \margindata
    [inouter]
    {\startMyEnumeration[title=\userdataparameter{title},reference=\userdataparameter{reference}]
     \getinlineuserdata
     \stopMyEnumeration}
\stopsetups

\defineuserdata [Enumeration] [alternative=enumeration]

\setuplayout
  [width=10cm,
   rightmargin=6cm]

\starttext

\input tufte
\startuserdata [Enumeration] [title={Jojo Mayer}]
\input jojomayer
\stopuserdata
\input zapf

\stoptext
```

which results in the following output

[image]