# ConTeXt: Issue with marginboxes and doublesided

Tags: context, double-sided

Playing around with this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539716/213111) I tried to use framed boxes on a doublesided document but there is a strange issue.

Why left boxes are not centered in (outer)margin like right ones ?

[image]

Here is a minimal example:

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]


\setuplayout[width=fit,
            height=270mm,
            rightmargin=60mm,
            rightmargindistance=5mm]


\defineframedtext[sideboxframed][frame=on,
                                framecolor=black,
                                rulethickness=1pt,
                                width=5cm,
                                offset=overlay,
                                align=normal]


\defineuserdataalternative[enumeration:sidebox][renderingsetup=sidenote:sidebox]


\startsetups[sidenote:sidebox]
\margindata[inouter]{
    \startsideboxframed
    \getinlineuserdata
    \stopsideboxframed
}
\stopsetups


\defineuserdata [sidebox] [alternative=enumeration:sidebox]




\starttext


\dorecurse{2}{\input knuth}
\startuserdata[sidebox]
    \input ward
\stopuserdata
\dorecurse{2}{\input knuth}
\startuserdata[sidebox]
    \input ward
\stopuserdata
\dorecurse{2}{\input knuth}
\startuserdata[sidebox]
    \input ward
\stopuserdata
\dorecurse{2}{\input knuth}
\startuserdata[sidebox]
    \input ward
\stopuserdata


\stoptext
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example.

Comment: When you add `\showframe` to your example you can see the frame if left aligned in the margin area on both sides.

Comment: Oh, you are right! Then, is there a way to center them on both sides without having to deal with margins distances, edges and stuff like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your example is how you set the value for the right margin of the page. When you use `width=fit` ConTeXt calculates the space with the values of the `rightmargin` and `rightmargindistance` which leaves no space between the margin area and the page border.

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4,oversized]

\setuplayout
  [width=fit,
   rightmargin=60mm,
   rightmargindistance=5mm,
   location=middle]

\showframe

\starttext
\page[dummy]
\stoptext
```

[image]

When you use now `\inouter` (or `\margindata[inouter]`) to put text in the margin area the content is aligned with the left margin of the area which leaves a space at the right side.

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4,oversized]

\setuplayout
  [width=fit,
   rightmargin=60mm,
   rightmargindistance=5mm,
   location=middle]

\showframe

\starttext
\inouter{\inframed[width=5cm]{Margin text}}
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

[image]

To avoid this you have to use a different method to change the value of the right margin. To do this you have to use `width=middle` for `\setuplayout` and set the space for the right side with the `cutspace` key. The value for `cutspace` should be larger than `rightmargin` and `rightmargindistance` combined to leave space between the margin area and the page border.

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4,oversized]

\setuplayout
  [width=middle,
   cutspace=60mm,
   rightmargin=50mm,
   rightmargindistance=5mm,
   location=middle]

\showframe

\starttext
\page[dummy]
\stoptext
```

[image]

To ensure the distance between the frame and the text block is the same on odd and even pages set the width of both to the same value. There is also no need for an extra frame because `margindata` provides a frame mechanism which can be accessed with `marginframed` but it's the best to create a new instance where you set your own style.

```
\setuppagenumbering [alternative=doublesided]

\setuplayout
  [              width=middle, % textwidth = paperwidth - backspace - cutspace
              cutspace=60mm,
           rightmargin=50mm,
   rightmargindistance=5mm]

\definemargindata   [sidebox] [inouter]
\definemarginframed [sidebox] [inouter]

\setupmarginframed
  [sidebox]
  [frame=on,
   rulethickness=1pt,
   width=5cm,
   offset=overlay,
   framecolor=black,
   align={normal,verytolerant}]


\defineuserdataalternative [enumeration:sidebox] [renderingsetup=sidenote:sidebox]

\showframe

\startsetups[sidenote:sidebox]
    \margindata[sidebox]{\getinlineuserdata}
\stopsetups

\defineuserdata [sidebox] [alternative=enumeration:sidebox]

\starttext

\startbuffer
    \dorecurse{2}{\input knuth}
    \startuserdata[sidebox]
        \input ward
    \stopuserdata
\stopbuffer

\dorecurse{4}{\getbuffer}

\stoptext
```